# HP Pavilion G4-1315dx and Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Wireless Networking

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, wireless-networking

As the title says, I have an HP Pavilion G4-1315dx Notebook.

Relevant Specs:

- AMD Quad-Core
- Realtek Wireless chipset
- Wireless "on/off" switch is the F12 key

Initially, I completely reformatted and installed Ubuntu 10.04, everything was working fine with the exception of the wireless networking.

I did extensive searching of Ubuntu documentation, online forums, and google, and found similar issues but none were exact matches to this machine.

I ensured I had the right linux drivers for the chipset, made sure it wasn't hard or soft blocked, and tried different network managers, ect. If it was a suggestion, I tried it. Nothing worked.

I reinstalled windows 7, got the drivers from HP, and the wireless works perfect.

From this I gathered that controlling the power to the wireless card through the F12 key must be the issue. I could never get the indicator light to change to white until I installed software called the HP connection manager.

So I reinstalled lucid and installed wine, to try to run the HP connection manager. This still doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Ideas on solving it?

I thought about also running lucid as a virtual box inside windows to see if that might work. Or even buying a USB networking card that is known to work with linux. Thank you in advance for the advice.

Comment: please add the exact model of your wifi card. I had a similar problem on an hp and my solution is to reboot and press the wifi switch when booting, so if the card is turned off will bee turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have Linux drivers installed correctly? You can verify that by booting Linux Mint that comes with drivers installed. However you can also try to install latest version of Ubuntu that may work. [Here](http://michkhoo.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-install-wireless-card-drivers-on.html) are also listed some alternative ways to get Wifi working.